# Javascript replace some parts of string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to hide parts of a string using javascript, I have the email:

```
hideparts@email.com
```

And I need to transform into:

```
hi****@email.com
```

And I need to display the email after the @, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RegExp might be good. [`Regex Editor`](http://regexr.com/6259c).

Leaving the first two letters and replacing the rest before the `@` to be replaced

```js
let str = 'hideparts@email.com';

console.log(str.replace(/(\w{2}).*?@/, '$1****@'));
```

Comment: This is good because it replaces the remaining letters with four asterisks as requested, not "however many remaining letters there were" asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way using map() and repeat()

```js
let email = "hideparts@email.com";
const obfuscate = str => str.split('@').map((e, i) => i === 0 ? e.slice(0, 2) + '*'.repeat(e.length - 2) : e).join('@');

console.log(obfuscate(email))
```

Comment: `'*'.repeat(e.length - 2)` is probably not ideal from a privacy POV; perhaps a hardcoded value would be better.

Answer (score 0):

First get your index of @
With

```
Var ind =str.indexof("@")
```

then loop from index 2 to ind and each loop replace this char with *

Answer (score 0):

I feel this could be achieved using `indexOf()` and a for loop.

```js
let email = 'hideparts@email.com';
let atPosition = email.indexOf('@'); //get @ position 
let startIndex = atPosition > 2 ? 2: 0; //handle case for really small email names
if(atPosition > -1){ 
for(let i = startIndex ; i < atPosition;i++){
email = email.substring(0, i) + '*' + email.substring(i + 1); 
}
}
console.log(email);
```

Using the `.subtstring()` method to replace a character in a string.
`email[i] = '*'` will not work, strings are immmutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve what you need.

```js
const str = 'abcdefgh@email.com';
const [contact, domain] = str.split('@');
const maskedMailId = contact.slice(0, 2) + '*'.repeat(contact.length - 2) + '@' + domain;
console.log(maskedMailId);
```